# How do I multiply a value in one table by a value in another table?

Tags: r

I have two tables: Table1 and Table2

| x | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 35904 |
| 2 | 40500 |

| x | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 25535 |
| 2 | 23235 |

How would I multiply the value of x = 1 in Table1 by the value of x = 2 in Table2?

Comment: `Table1$Value[Table1$x == 1] * Table2$Value[Table2$x == 2]`

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm not sure if I am meant to thank you in this section?